# Python code prints output without print() command

Tags: python, python-3.6

I've just started learning Python, and I've run into a small problem.
I want to run a sample code given in the book I'm learning from. I am getting the desired output, but I'm also getting an output where I don't need it - there's no explanation in the book.

Here's the code:

```
>>> vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
>>> word = input("Provide a word to look for vowels in it: ")
Provide a word to look for vowels in it: 
Sample Word

>>> found = {}
>>> for letter in word:
...     if letter in vowels:
...         found.setdefault(letter, 0)
...         found[letter] += 1
... 
0
0
0
>>> for k,v in sorted(found.items()):
...     print(k,' was found ', v, ' times.')
... 
a  was found  1  times.
```

This code is used to find out the number of times a vowel appears in the input. The last output (which is in the print() command) is needed. However, the first for...loop gives the numeric output of how many times each vowel appears. I don't need that **output**. Any idea what's going on here?

Just in case it matters, I'm using Head First Python to learn.

Comment: You are using an interactive environment.  If you ran as a script this would not be the case.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50631177/edit) to include more information.

Comment: Hey chrisz, I'm writing it as a script (as far as I can understand) and then running it - this is copied and pasted from the output. Please let me know if I'm doing something stupidly wrong here, which I'm sure I am...

Comment: The `>>>` indicates clearly that you are in an iinteractive python console.

Comment: That's not a problem, but the console echoes back to the screen function returning values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the return value of

```
found.setdefault(letter, 0)
```

As a letter key is not found, a new letter key is added with the value 0.
This value is returned from `setdefault` and the console is showing it.

Were you running this as a an executable file script, or with `python script.py` and this return value would be simply ignored, as you don't assign it to anything, when calling the function.

Comment: I saved it as a .py file and ran it after reading your answer - worked as needed. Thanks!